# How to count the number of elements in a set of rows selected based on a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large `DataFrame` with many duplicate values. The unique values are stored in `List1`. I'd like to do the following:

1. Select a few rows that contain each of the values present in the list.
2. Iterate over the selected rows and count the number of non NaN elements
3. If the count value is greater than or equal to 2, store it in a new list. Each component in `List1` should be added to `eq_list` only if **all** the count values for the 'eq' are >=2.

A simplified sample input:

```
List1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','X','Y','Z']

Sample DF 'ABC':

        EQ1  EQ2   EQ3
0       A    NaN   NaN
1       X    Y     NaN
2       A    X     C
3       D    E     F
4       G    H     B
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
eq_list = ['B','C','D','E','F','G','H','X','Y']
```

The codelet I tried:

```
for eq in List1:
    MCS=ABC.loc[MCS_old[:] ==eq]
    MCS = MCS.reset_index(drop=True)
    for index_new in range(0,len(MCS)-1):
        if int(MCS.iloc[[index_new]].count(axis=1))>2:
            eq_list.append(raw_input(eq))
            print(eq_list)
```

I hope that I have made the issue clear.

Comment: Am I right to assume that `eq_list` is a set of unique letters ?

Comment: 'eq_list' is the final output and is a subset of 'List1', which has NO repetitions. So, yes. I think I explained it better in my last comment in the answer thread

Comment: PLs see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The below identifies the `set` of (unique) values that occur in rows with more than 2 non-`NaN` values, eliminates those that also occur in rows with less than 2 non`NaN` values. Avoids using loops.

First, get `set` of unique values in the part of `df` that does not meet the missing values restriction (and adding `.strip()` to address a data issue mentioned in the comments):

```
na_threshold = 1
not_enough_non_nan = df[df.count(axis=1) <= 1].values.flatten().astype(str)
not_enough_non_nan = set([str(l).strip() for l in not_enough_non_nan if not l == 'nan'])

{'A'}
```

Next, identify the `set` of values that do meet your restriction:

```
enough_non_nan = df[df.count(axis=1) > 1].values.flatten().astype(str)
enough_non_nan = set([str(l).strip() for l in enough_non_nan if not l == 'nan'])

{'H', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'D', 'X', 'F', 'A', 'Y', 'G'}
```

Finally, take the `set` difference between the above to eliminate values do not always meet the restriction:

```
result = sorted(enough_non_nan - not_enough_non_nan)

['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'X', 'Y']
```

Comment: No @Stefan it won't. I can't convert it to a 1D list because the table I showed here is just a sample and the real one has thousands of rows with scores of rows with one or two NaN values. I specifically need something to scan for rows with each of the elements in 'List1' and then re-index them an then check the number of the non NaN elements in each of the new rows and only then update the new list

Comment: But you are trying to identify the values in `List1` that always have more than 2 non `NaN` values, ie they do not occur in the the rows with `.count()<=1` while they do occur elsewhere?

Comment: I'm trying to identify the values in "List1" for whose presence in a row there is at least 2 non NaN values. So for each element 'V' in 'List1' it has to check for rows in 'ABC' that contain 'V' and then make sure that every row with 'V' in it has at least 2 non NaN values. If YES, add 'V' to eq_list

Comment: I think the above does exactly that. `enough_non_nan` has all values with more than 1 non missing values. `non_enough_non_nan` has all values for which this is not the case. `result` has all the values that are in `enough_non_nan` but NOT in `not_enough..` and are also in `List1`. It's also fast because it uses `numpy` and `set`.

Comment: I get the point but I don't think it follows the algorithm that I need (my previous comment) and following the specific algorithm is pretty important. Also, if I'm to change the  minimum number of non NaN values desired, where can I do that?

Comment: Added a variable `nan_threshold` so you can see where the restriction is applied and how to change it. The above code solves the problem of identifying the values in `List1` that exclusively occur in rows with less missing values than allowed per `nan_threshold`. As for a specific algorithm, ie, a specific sequence of steps to follow to accomplish that, I don't know.

Comment: @StefanJansen What is the purpose of `.intersection(set(List1))` ? Could it be dropped out?

Comment: Can be dropped if the `df` only contains values in `List1`. Just added to make sure no values are captured that for some reason are not in `List1`.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work if the intersection part is not there. It shows type error. Even though df contains values only in 'List1'.

Comment: Can't replicate that, works fine when I run it. Both `not_enough_non_nan` and `enough_non_nan` should be of `type` `set`, so the difference would be  a `set` which works as input for `list()`.

Comment: @StefanJansen `Select a few rows that contain each of the values present in the list` exactly states that

Comment: Not sure, couldn't the rows contain each of the values in `List1` and also some other values? Didn't seem to rule it out, so just wanted to make sure. But OP just said `df` in fact only has values from `List1` so looks like we're good here and I'll remove.

Comment: I mean by few I meant all the rows where the value taken from 'List1' appears AT LEAST' once in that row. And yes, it has values only present in the list. Actually, I created 'List1' from the df initially. I just realized that without the intersection, the error is the same as when I try to run @SergeyBushmanov 's solution.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov's solution is very similar using loops. If you get a `TypeError` you may want to check `type` of inputs.

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts to help me guys even though I didn't get a proper solution. Thanks a lot to you both ! If you want we can take this conversation to a chat so that the comments section isn't too crowded with messages

Comment: Happy to help but you'd have to let us know where the answers fail in providing a solution. If your actual data are not well represented by the sample, you could update the sample, for instance.

Comment: The thing is 'enough' is creating duplicates of the values in the df and the twin value differs from the original just by a space and is hence considered as a different value. Also, a few values have only the ones with the extra space and so they are deleted
Should I delete this question and create 2 new questions that actually carry out the steps that I need?

Comment: You could just iterate over `enough` as and eliminate the white space: `[x.strip() for x in list(enough_non_nan)]`. See update.

Comment: The `strip` command is not working. I'll post a new question with the required sequence of steps. Thanks again!

Comment: Works fine, just need to convert to `str` as there are `np.nan`. See update. Also, don't comment with `doesn't work`, that's not constructive in finding a solution. Always state the error message.

Comment: For sake of completeness, added step to deal with `np.nan` and remove the whitespace issue.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have:

```
df
    EQ1 EQ2 EQ3
0   A   NaN NaN
1   X   Y   NaN
2   A   X   C
3   D   E   F
4   G   H   B
```

Then, you may proceed as follows:

```
dft = df.T
output_set = set()
prune_set =  set()
for column in dft:
    arr = dft[column].dropna().values
    if len(arr) >=2:
        output_set |= set(arr)
    else:
        prune_set |= set(arr)
sorted(output_set - prune_set)
['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'X', 'Y']
```

Comment: It does work on the example you provided and produces desired output. Do you mean it "does not work" on another df?

Comment: Yes it doesn't work on the  real df that I'm using,which has a similar structure as the example I provided but differs in size greatly. It creates new list elements with the same value and then adds an extra space and displays which is an error

Comment: Sorry, can't help without seeing your real data