# How to select the rows that contain a specific value in at least one of the elements in a row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` `DF`and a list, say `List1`. `List1` is created from the `DF` and it has the elements present in `DF` but without repetitions. I need to do the following:
1. Select the rows of `DF` that contain a specific element from `List1` (for instance, iterating all the elements in `List1`) 
2. Re-index them from 0 to whatever the number of rows are because the rows selected may have non continuous indices.

SAMPLE INPUT:

```
List1=['Apple','Orange','Banana','Pineapple','Pear','Tomato','Potato']
Sample DF
  EQ1      EQ2      EQ3
0 Apple    Orange   NaN
1 Banana   Potato   NaN
2 Pear     Tomato   Pineapple
3 Apple    Tomato   Pear
4 Tomato   Potato   Banana
```

Now if I want access to the rows that contain `Apple`, those would be 0 and 3. But I'd like them renamed as 0 and 1(Re-indexing). After `Apple` is searched, the next element from `List1` should be taken and similar steps are to be carried out. I have other operations to perform after this, so I need to loop the whole process throughout `List1`. I hope I have explained it well and here is my codelet for the same, which is not working:

```
for eq in List1:
    MCS=DF.loc[MCS_Simp_green[:] ==eq] #Indentation was missing
    MCS= MCS.reset_index(drop=True)
    <Remaining operations>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
List1=['Apple','Orange','Banana','Pineapple','Pear','Tomato','Potato']

for eq in List1:
    #print df.isin([eq]).any(1)
    #print df[df.isin([eq]).any(1)]
    df1 = df[df.isin([eq]).any(1)].reset_index(drop=True)  
    print df1

     EQ1     EQ2   EQ3
0  Apple  Orange   NaN
1  Apple  Tomato  Pear
     EQ1     EQ2  EQ3
0  Apple  Orange  NaN
      EQ1     EQ2     EQ3
0  Banana  Potato     NaN
1  Tomato  Potato  Banana
    EQ1     EQ2        EQ3
0  Pear  Tomato  Pineapple
     EQ1     EQ2        EQ3
0   Pear  Tomato  Pineapple
1  Apple  Tomato       Pear
      EQ1     EQ2        EQ3
0    Pear  Tomato  Pineapple
1   Apple  Tomato       Pear
2  Tomato  Potato     Banana
      EQ1     EQ2     EQ3
0  Banana  Potato     NaN
1  Tomato  Potato  Banana
```

For storing values you can use `dict` comprehension:

```
dfs = {eq: df[df.isin([eq]).any(1)].reset_index(drop=True) for eq in List1}

print dfs['Apple']
     EQ1     EQ2   EQ3
0  Apple  Orange   NaN
1  Apple  Tomato  Pear

print dfs['Orange']
     EQ1     EQ2  EQ3
0  Apple  Orange  NaN
```

Comment: @VachanBhat - It is easy check what was first. See [my revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37230933/revisions) and [Stefans revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37230866/revisions).

Comment: Hello @jezrael  Just a doubt, does this algorithm have a limitation that it works for only small lists or small resulting dfs? For me in my original list, it is returning a null df for a couple of values in `List1`

Comment: You can check some of probleamatic values by `df.isin(['word_returning_empty_df']).any(1)` and if this code return only `False` values this element is not in df.

Comment: Its returning a null df even if the element is there.This is happening only for a couple of values. And its not random. It's always the same two values. The codeline you provided also returns `False` even though those values are in there

Comment: Interesting. But maybe there is `space` before or after these two `strings` e.g. `' value'` ? Or this strings contains some unicode chars?

Comment: I checked all that. In fact the values in the list were created using `strip()`. So no spaces. I'm really puzzled. Well, those two values don't appear in the first column ever. They are always in the second or third column

Comment: Is possible write to csv one of row with problematic value and then check it? Are data confidental?

Comment: The data is kind of confidential. I got the bug in the code. For example, in the example I provided, `Tomato` has 3 rows containing it and the output you provided looks fine. But when I run the code on my data, it selects only the last one i.e. `Tomato Potato Banana` and the rest are ignored as they don't have `Tomato` in the first column

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks anyway!! The problem was that when I created the list, I removed the extra spaces (if any) and I failed to do so in the `DataFrame`. Now I did that and the code works like a charm!!!

Comment: Super, I am very glad that you found solution of problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can identify the items in the `list` and collect the resulting new `DataFrame`s like so:

```
data_frames = {}
for l in List1:
    data_frames[l] = df[df.isin([l]).any(1)].reset_index(drop=True)
    print(l, data_frames[l].index.tolist())
```

to get:

```
Apple [0, 1]
Orange [0]
Banana [0, 1]
Pineapple [0]
Pear [0, 1]
Tomato [0, 1, 2]
Potato [0, 1]
```

The new `DataFrame` objects are contained in the `dictionary` `data_frames`:

```
data_frames['Apple']

     EQ1     EQ2   EQ3
0  Apple  Orange   NaN
1  Apple  Tomato  Pear
```

Comment: Will this create new dataframes with indices from 0 onwards? Because my remaining operation is on the resulting "Normalized" dataframes

Comment: Thank you! It works !! Well both have a similar solution ! I don't know who posted first But anyway thanks guys!

Comment: Actually no. I adjusted my solution because I just spent one hour trying to solve a related issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228565/how-to-count-the-number-of-elements-in-a-set-of-rows-selected-based-on-a-conditi/37229139#37229139 and remembered that it was important to keep all the columns. So I changed my solution to keep keep the other other values form the list. Great idea @jezrael to capture the result in a dictionary!

Comment: @StefanJansen - no problem. Nice day.