# How to perform operations on rows of Dataframes which contain elements linked to a value in another Dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two Dataframes `DF` and `DF2` and a list `List1`. To keep it simple I'll use a sample input. `DF` and `DF2` contain elements which are in `List1`. `DF` has a random arrangement of these elements with some `NaN` values and in `DF2`, these elements are linked with a number. This is what I intend to do: 
1. Iterate over `List1` and choose the rows in `DF` which have that particular element from `List1` (**I have already done this**) 
2.  In each of the rows, perform a multiplication of the values associated with the strings in the rows (which are in `DF2`)

Part 2 has puzzled me for quite some time now. I thought of different things but I can't get any idea of an algorithm at all. I can't get to link the strings in `DF` and their values in `DF2`. Please help!

```
List1=['Apple','Orange','Banana','Pineapple','Pear','Tomato','Potato']
Sample DF
   EQ1      EQ2      EQ3
0 Apple    Orange   NaN
1 Banana   Potato   NaN
2 Pear     Tomato   Pineapple
3 Apple    Tomato   Pear
4 Tomato   Potato   Banana

DF2
  Name      Value
Apple       3.21
Orange      4.32
Banana      5.22
Pineapple   0.01
Pear        4.89
Tomato      7.55
Potato      6.49
```

For doing Part 2: For example if I select the rows with the element `Banana`, the first row to be accessed is `Banana Potato NaN`. Now `Banana` is associated with `5.22` and `Potato` is associated with `6.49` in `DF2`. I'd like to change the value of the selected string (in this case, `Banana`) to 1 temporarily and then I'd like them to be multiplied. (1*6.49 in this case). Of course `NaN` shouldn't be included in this. Also the number of columns of `DF` (the length of rows) are not always 3 (as shown). It is a variable. As I'm using a loop, this product calculation should be done for all the elements of `List1`. It'd be great if someone can help me with Part2. 
Desired output for `Banana` **only**.

```
List_output=[6.49, 48.9995]
```

EXPLANATION OF THE OUTPUT: Banana is present in 2 rows only. Hence there are only two values in the Output list. The first is 6.49 because that row has only two non `NaN` values and one of them is the selected value, `Banana`.Therefore, the value associated with `Banana` is changed to 1 **temporarily** and the rest of the values are kept as they are. This has to be done for all the values in `List1`. Hope I made it clear

Comment: Can you add desired output of input? `Series`?

Comment: I just edited it to include a partial desired output in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first create `dict` by [`to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html), then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) equal value in loop by `1` and remove `NaN` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by `1` too. Then you can replace all values by `dict` `d` and multiple all columns. Last you can store `lists` to dictionary `lis`:

```
d= DF2.set_index('Name').to_dict()
print (d)
{'Value': {'Banana': 5.2199999999999998, 'Pineapple': 0.01, 
           'Apple': 3.21, 'Tomato': 7.5499999999999998,
           'Orange': 4.3200000000000003, 
           'Pear': 4.8899999999999997, 'Potato': 6.4900000000000002}}

lis = {}    
for eq in List1:
    #http://stackoverflow.com/a/37230933/2901002
    df = DF[DF.isin([eq]).any(1)].reset_index(drop=True)  
    df.replace(eq,1, inplace=True)
    df.fillna(1, inplace=1)
    df.replace(d['Value'], inplace=True)
    li = df.EQ1.values * df.EQ2.values * df.EQ3.values
    lis[eq] = li.tolist() 
    print (li.tolist())
[4.32, 36.9195]
[3.21]
[6.49, 48.9995]
[36.9195]
[0.0755, 24.2355]
[0.0489, 15.6969, 33.8778]
[5.22, 39.410999999999994]

print (lis['Banana'])    
[6.49, 48.9995]
```

Another solution with [`product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.product.html), which is more general, because works if number of columns in `DF` is not a constant:

```
dfs = {}
for eq in List1:
    df = DF[DF.isin([eq]).any(1)].reset_index(drop=True)  
    df.replace(eq,1, inplace=True)
    df.fillna(1, inplace=1)
    df.replace(d['Value'], inplace=True)
    li = df.product(axis=1)
    dfs[eq] = li.tolist() 
    print (li.tolist())

[4.3200000000000003, 36.919499999999999]
[3.21]
[6.4900000000000002, 48.999499999999998]
[36.919499999999999]
[0.075499999999999998, 24.235499999999998]
[0.048899999999999999, 15.696899999999999, 33.877800000000001]
[5.2199999999999998, 39.410999999999994]      

print (dfs['Banana'])    
[6.4900000000000002, 48.999499999999998]

print (DF)   
      EQ1     EQ2        EQ3
0   Apple  Orange        NaN
1  Banana  Potato        NaN
2    Pear  Tomato  Pineapple
3   Apple  Tomato       Pear
4  Tomato  Potato     Banana
```

Comment: Well the number of columns in `DF` is not a constant and it can be 3 or 4 or something else. Will this work for a general case?

Comment: The product one is more general is it?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Second solution is more general, because `product` multiple all columns.

Comment: I'll try this on my code and let you know. Line 3 of the "product" solution is a bit different for me. The way I stored the dictionary is `df[eq]` and not `df` like above so that I can isolate those rows and perform these operations on those selected rows only and then continue on to other sets of rows. Is this better?

Comment: Yes, I combine previous [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37230933/2901002) with step2. What is difference? Do you think a lot `99999` ?

Comment: It's a minor thing. I'll figure it out. I have another doubt. Will the `inplace = True` make the replacement permanent ? Because the change of value to 1 is supposed to be temporary

Comment: In loop I create temporary dataframe `df`, where are change values, fillna, replace by 1.... But main Dataframe `DF` is not changed. You can check it by `print (DF)`  under my code, I give it to solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112592/discussion-between-vachan-bhat-and-jezrael).

Comment: Hello! Everything was fine till just now when I got an error on a line which was previously working fine
`Traceback (most recent call last):` <br/>
`File "C:\Python35-32\My_Scripts\test1.py", line 87, in <module>` <br/>
`eq_temp_df_quant.replace(eq_prob['Value'], inplace=True)` <br/>
`TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'` <br/>
These are the first 3 lines and the last line of the error :/
All I did was add a value to the very first dataframe

Comment: Maybe help casting to `float` column `Value` : `DF2['Value'] = DF2['Value'].astype(float)`

Comment: But if it works, how is it possible now not? Data was changed? Or some update? It is really interesting.

Comment: I just added one row to `DF` . For example, the new first row is `Kiwi NaN NaN`. A totally different value with nothing in column 2 and 3. and I added it to `DF2` and `List1` as well.I have no clue what's going on !

Comment: So, you add `Name` as `string` and value as `float`? What is `type` of last value (if you add row to the end) in column `value` in `DF2` ? `print type(DF2.iloc[-1, DF2.columns.get_loc('Value')])`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112814/discussion-between-vachan-bhat-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to `merge` DF and DF2 three times, like this.

```
In [69]: DF
Out[69]: 
      EQ1     EQ2        EQ3
0   Apple  Orange        NaN
1  Banana  Potato        NaN
2    Pear  Tomato  Pineapple
3   Apple  Tomato       Pear
4  Tomato  Potato     Banana

In [70]: new_cols = ['V' + c for c in DF]

In [72]: for c, new_c in zip(DF, new_cols):
    ...:     DF = DF.merge(DF2.rename(columns={'Value': new_c}),
    ...:                   how='left', left_on=c, right_on='Name')
    ...:     

In [73]: DF[new_cols]
Out[73]: 
   VEQ1  VEQ2  VEQ3
0  3.21  4.32   NaN
1  5.22  6.49   NaN
2  4.89  7.55  0.01
3  3.21  7.55  4.89
4  7.55  6.49  5.22

In [74]: DF[new_cols].fillna(1.).product(axis=1)
Out[74]: 
0     13.867200
1     33.877800
2      0.369195
3    118.511595
4    255.777390
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm really sorry that I wrote the question a bit wrong. Now I edited it and its fine now

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a use case for `df.replace`, which conveniently accepts a series.

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
'''
   EQ1      EQ2      EQ3
0 Apple    Orange   NaN
1 Banana   Potato   NaN
2 Pear     Tomato   Pineapple
3 Apple    Tomato   Pear
4 Tomato   Potato   Banana
'''), sep=r' +')

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(
'''
  Name      Value
Apple       3.21
Orange      4.32
Banana      5.22
Pineapple   0.01
Pear        4.89
Tomato      7.55
Potato      6.49
'''), sep=r' +')


# convert df to series
s2 = df2.set_index('Name').Value

df3 = df1.replace(s2).product(axis=1)

# In [19]: q.df3
# Out[19]:
# 0     13.867200
# 1     33.877800
# 2      0.369195
# 3    118.511595
# 4    255.777390
# dtype: float64
```