# How to obtain the number of lists(rows) that contain a specific value(string) in at least one of the elements in a row(list)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

The question is pretty straightforward . I would like to know how to obtain the number of lists(rows) that contain a string which exists in at least one of the lists(rows) where my data is stored in the form of a list of lists with each sub-list containing strings. I checked this([How to select the rows that contain a specific value in at least one of the elements in a row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37230696/how-to-select-the-rows-that-contain-a-specific-value-in-at-least-one-of-the-elem)) out but my data is not in the form of a data frame and I don't have enough reputation points to comment on there.

My data looks something like this:

```
[['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'document'], ['this', 'document', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document'], ['and', 'this', 'is', 'the', 'third', 'one'], ['is', 'this', 'the', 'first', 'document']]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Given that:**

```
my_list = [['this', 'is', 'the', 'first', 'document'], ['this', 'document', 'is', 'the', 'second', 'document'], ['and', 'this', 'is', 'the', 'third', 'one'], ['is', 'this', 'the', 'first', 'document']]
```

**And you want to search if `'my_string'` exists in your rows**

**Then you can have:**

```
counter = 0

for row in my_list :
    if 'my_string' in row:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```